# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn is not accessible due level protection

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` (dGVProductos) on a Father Form and I add a `CheckBoxColumn` (SelectdGV) and I put in `DataGridView` Properties - Modifiers - Public, but when I try to use it in a `Form` Son, it tells me that I cannot access it due to its level of protection. The method where I try to use it is `Eliminar()` on the Form Son. SelectdGV appears in red line and it does not let me compile it.

```
public override void Eliminar()
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> rows_with_checked_column = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dGVProductos.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[SelectdGV.Name].Value) == true)
        {
            rows_with_checked_column.Add(row);
        }
    }
// Do what you want with the check rows
}
```

Comment: Since this seems to be a access level problem, can you post the full code from both the parent and the child classes (where those properties are declared)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can address the column name as you are because the column name `SelectdGV` is internal to the `DataGridView` object. When you try to use the variable `SelectdGV` as you are in your code, it won’t be accessible without referencing the DataGridView `dGVProductos`. To fix this and use it the way your code is currently, you could change your `if` condition like below:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[dGVProductos.Columns[2].Name].Value) == true) {
```

Where "2" is the column number you are seeking. This implies you don’t know what the column name is but it’s in column 3. This change will get your code working. However, since you DO know the column name… simply use the column string “name” value like below to identify the check box column and it should work properly. I added a check to ignore the new row added if the DataGridView allows users to add rows. Hope this helps.

```
public void Eliminar() {
  List<DataGridViewRow> rows_with_checked_column = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dGVProductos.Rows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["SelectdGV"].Value) == true) {
        rows_with_checked_column.Add(row);
        MessageBox.Show("Row: " + row.Cells[0].Value + ", " + row.Cells[1].Value + ", " + row.Cells[2].Value);
      }
    }
  }
  // Do what you want with the check rows
}
```